# Javascript compare 3 values

Tags: javascript

I have 3 values that I want to compare f, g and h. I have some code to check that they all equal each other and that none of them are null. I've had a look online but could not find anything that seemed to answer my query. Currently I am checking the code in the following way...

```
if(g == h && g == f && f == h && g != null && f != null && h != null)
{
//do something
}
```

This is quite long winded and I might be adding more values, so I was just wondering if there is a quicker way to check that none of the values are null and that all the values equal each other?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: will you be ok with putting those values in an array?

Comment: You do not have to check all the variables if they are `!= null`..  If they are equal between them, you can check only one against `null`. The same with checking `f == h`.. if both `f` and `h` are equal to `g` you do not have to check those two ..

Comment: have you compared the trade offs of putting all the var into an array?

Comment: If first three equations will be true then you must check only one variable to test if it is not null so:

Comment: Yes I could put them into an array, would it be easier to check them all if they were in an array?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You could shorten that to

```
if(g === h && g === f && g !== null)
{
//do something
}
```

---

For an actual way to compare multiple values (*regardless of their number*)
(*inspired by/ simplified [@Rohan Prabhu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9973394/128165) answer*)

```
function areEqual(){
   var len = arguments.length;
   for (var i = 1; i< len; i++){
      if (arguments[i] === null || arguments[i] !== arguments[i-1])
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

and call this with

```
if( areEqual(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) )
{
//do something
}
```

---

And a more recent approach

```js
function areEqualNotNull(values) {
  if (values[0] === null) return false;

  return values.every(value => value === values[0]);
}
```

Comment: You could even omit the `!= null`

Comment: @m90, why ? what if all are null ?

Comment: @m90 buy what if all of them are null? then it will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: If all of them are null `Boolean(g)` will be `false`: http://jsfiddle.net/SFDRK/ Or am I missing something?

Comment: @m90.. ah ok.. i thought you meant to remove the whole `g != null`  part.. But if you are comparing boolean values and they are all false ? it should return true according to specs..

Comment: @m90 true, but that also goes for all falsy values, the OP’s asked specifically for `null` http://jsfiddle.net/SFDRK/1/

Answer (score 37):

What about

```
(new Set([a,b,c])).size === 1
```

Comment: That's definitely a very elegant solution that I'd never have considered. I wonder if it has any disadvantages.

Comment: Nice solution!
keep in mind, @Phil, that 1(Number) and "1"(String) will be treated as different values

Comment: Very elegant. The size property of Set returns the number of unique elements in a Set object.

Comment: @Astridax disadvantages are that it allocates and garbage collects two objects (slow) and doesn't short circuit (also slow). But might be premature optimization not to use it if it's cleanest.

Comment: Also, OP says "none of them are null" but `new Set([null, null, null]).size === 1` is true, so this doesn't really fulfill the specification. That said, not being sure whether numbers are null probably indicates a deeper design problem.

Answer (score 20):

Works for any number of items.

## ES5

```js
if ([f, g, h].every(function (v, i, a) {
  return (
    v === a[0] &&
    v !== null
  );
})) {
  // Do something
}
```

## ES2015

```js
if ([f, g, h].every((v, i, a) => 
  v === a[0] &&
  v !== null
)) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you write a function where you give an array with all the values you want to compare and then iterate through the array to compare the values which each other:

```
function compareAllValues(a) {
     for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         if (a[i] === null) { return false }
         for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (a[j] !== a[i]) { return false }
         }
     }

     return true;
}
```

that should be it, I think :)

Comment: Your soln. is much space complex than it should be.

Answer (score 4):

Write a simple function:

```
var checkAllArguments = function() {
    var len = arguments.length;
    var obj;

    if(len == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if(arguments[0] == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            obj = arguments[0];
        }
    }

    for(var i=1; i<len; i++) {
        if(arguments[i] == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if(obj == arguments[i]) {
            continue;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Now, to check multiple arguments, all you have to do is:

```
if(checkAllArguments(g, h, f)) {
   // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of string and check the existance of next value in there

```
compareAnswers(a1: string, a2: string, a3: string): boolean {
   this.compareAnswerArr.push(a1);
if (this.compareAnswerArr.includes(a2) == false) {
  this.compareAnswerArr.push(a2);
  if (this.compareAnswerArr.includes(a3) == false) {
    return true;
  } else return false;
}
else return false;}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add a `distinct` function to `Array.prototype`:

```
Array.prototype.distinct = function() {
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (result.indexOf(this[i]) == -1) {
            result.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Then do:

```
var myArray = [f, g, h];
if (myArray.indexOf(null) == -1 && myArray.unique().length == 1)
{
    // no nulls and all elements have the same value!
}
```

Comment: Note that I no longer recommend this

Comment: Thanks for the note, but if you no longer recommend it, consider [edit]ing it to something you do recommend or deleting it altogether. It's perfectly fine for answers to change as best practices move on.

Comment: You also have a typo: `unique()` rather than `distinct()`. Best to use `===` rather than `==`.