# compare values of 3 javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare the 3 javascript variable values and they are equal, need to perform a function.

```
if(vcount === tcount === lcount){

//do something;
}
```

and (as per [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973323/javascript-compare-3-values))

```
if((vcount == tcount) && (tcount == lcount)){

    //do something;
    }
```

But its not working for me.

Comment: Or did you want `(vcount === tcount) && (tcount === lcount)` What do you mean by not working.

Comment: can u post a jsfiddle which shows what is not working

Comment: Your second code example should be working fine

Comment: Your code should work.  Better check [difference between == and ===](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: "Not working" is an insufficient description for anyone to know how to help you.

Comment: Which code is not working? Please improve your question.

Comment: It's unlikely that comparing 3 variables, is actually good business logic/ or implementation practice. I've had 20+ years experience and I feel a smell -- _it doesn't sound like any robust or correct logic I ever heard of._

Comment: This is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HKbB2/ and your code works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

consider the following code-

```
1===1===1
```

As `===` operator is **left-right associative** hence the first part that is `1===1` is evaluated first.

`1===1` returns `true`. then there is the following comparison

```
true===1
```

Which is definitely `false` because **boolean** `true` is not same as `1` because `===` considers **value as well as datatype**.

### So whenever the 3rd parameter is **not `boolean`** it will definitely return `false` if you use `===` to compare them. Hence you should ***always use the 2nd syntax*** to compare any 3 values.

Answer (score 2):

Try with Conditional(Ternary) Operator (?:) which will help. Please refer below example
This is one way of alternative solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= getResult(7,5,5);
}

function getResult(x,y,z){
 return x===y?x===z?true:false:false;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @FelixKling : agree with u

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what others have said, verify your variables are the correct type.  For example, one might be a character and another other is an integer.  Try to verify they are all the same by doing toString(value), or parseInt(value,10).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. I prefer this way to work with n variables

```
    function isEqual1() {
        var val = arguments[0],
            equal = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            equal = (arguments[i] === val);
            if (!equal) return false;
        }
        return equal;
    }
```

else

```
    function isEqual2() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        var equal = args.join(',').replace(new RegExp(args[0], "ig"), '').replace(/,/g, "");
        return equal.length == 0;
    }
```

Results

```
    console.log(isEqual1(1, true, false, "xyz"));
    console.log(isEqual1(true, true, true, true));
    console.log(isEqual2(true, 123, true, true));
    console.log(isEqual2(true, true, true, true));
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/p5aa7/7/

Answer (score 0):

A more functional approach is to create a set and than check the size of the set:

```
const things = new Set(["b","b","b"]);

if (things.size === 1 ){
  console.log('Only one thing!');
}
```