# Comparing 3 identical values for equality using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on studying for an entry test, and being self learned I have been working a lot of functions problems.  this one has stumped me,
I a to write a function testing to see if 3 values are equal.  The code i have tired is:

```
Function equal(a,b,c){ 
  return a==b==c; 
}
```

as well as:

```
function equal(a,b,c){
  let newEqual=a==b;
  return newEqual===c
}
```

I feel like I am missing something rather simple but have not been able to put my finger on it.
thank you in advance for any insight

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Function needs a new, please read [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) vs [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: Also read [== Equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) vs [===Identity or strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) operators

Comment: Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973323/javascript-compare-3-values) answer your question.

Comment: All, this is not a "do my homework for me" site. Only specific questions should be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether all three variables are equal or not, use `&&` operator to add on queries.

`&&` returns true if all conditions are true.

```
function equal(a,b,c){
    return a == b && b == c;
}
```

As mentioned by @mplungjan, for strict comparison use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: I did have to switch to the following
a===b&&b===c so that the result would come up false if there was a string element ex('1',2,3) needed to return false, but thank you for your help.  This set me where I needed to go.

Answer (score 1):

`a == b == c` will be evaluated as :

`a == b` then checks the result ( `true` ) and compares it with `c` => `true == c` which is `false` :

```js
const a = 5;
const b = 5;
const c = 5;

const result = a == b == c ;

console.log(result); // false

const a1 = 5;
const b1 = 5;
const c1 = true;

const result1 = a1 == b1 == c1 ;

console.log(result1); // true
```

You should compare them separately :

```js
const a = 5;
const b = 5;
const c = 5;

const result = a == b && b == c ;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: [== Equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) vs [===Identity or strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) operators

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function equal(a,b,c){ 
  return a==b && b==c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by doing the following:

```js
function equal(a,b,c){
  return (a==b) && (b==c)
}
```

That way you are checking if a == b is true, and b == c is true then all three are equal. In other words, true && true = true