# Comparing Rows in javascript for Tic tac toe

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
b[1] ==b[9]
true
b[1] ==b[5]
true
b[5] == b[9]
true
b[1]==b[5]==b[9]
false
```

Javascript got me crazy. Does anyone have solution to it.
I was making tic tac toe and checking whether rows of a board are equal. Even if they are equal it shows false.

Comment: show the code please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript compare 3 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973323/javascript-compare-3-values)

Comment: @Thecave3 help!

Comment: tic-tac-toe usually only has 9 boxes, so b[9] would be out of bounds in JavaScript since JS indexes from 0 (unless you're manually make it size 10). Assuming you are using a size 10 array, indices 1, 5, and 9 would make up a diagonal

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Python, but like most programming languages, the `==` operator doesn't chain (except with booleans), so saying `b[1]==b[5]==b[9]`, assuming that `b[1]==b[5]` is true, is equal to saying `true==b[9]`, which doesn't make sense.

You need to use the `&&` operator (which is the same as Python's `and` operator):

```js
b[1] ==b[9]
true
b[1] ==b[5]
true
b[5] == b[9]
true
b[1]==b[5] && b[5]==b[9]
true
```

Comment: thanks , it is difficult for people like me coming from python.